# Python: Verifying a string represents a valid US currency value?

Tags: python, currency

How can I verify that a string represents a valid US currency value?

The string might be composed strictly of digits, or optionally have a dollar sign, commas, etc.

Context: I wish to verify a string is a proper dollar value, and then convert it to a number after removing or otherwise handling the non-numeric characters.

Comment: can you give us some examples of your dataset? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular Expression

Example: `\$?(-?(\d+[,.])*\d+)`

```py
import re
re.match("\$?(-?(\d+[,.])*\d+)", "$-12,000.01")  # match
re.match("\$?(-?(\d+[,.])*\d+)", "$-12,000.01").group(1)  # extract matched value
>>> '-12,000.01'
re.sub('[,$]', '', '$-12,000.01')                  # remove comma and dollar sign
>>> '-12000.01'
float(re.sub('[,$]', '', '$-12,000.01'))           # convert to float if the result doesn't contain any special character such as comma
>>> -12000.01
```

Add more cases to the regular expression if there are any in your dataset.

There can be many edge-cases that are invalid such as **13.000,000**

This regular expression will fix it: `\$?(-?\d*(\d+,)*\.?\d+)`.

So add as many cases as you need.

Comment: can you put `float` in front of re.sub? the output is a string. if he wants a number, i think you should put that = ]